# How to call Prism Event in Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

I'm new to WPF. Currently, I want to allow my Add button to add item by using either single click or double click. However, when I try to double click, it ends up fire single click event twice. Code in XAML as below:

```
<Button.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding Path=AddCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding Path=AddCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" />
```

I found solution online which is to use **DispatcherTimer** in order to solve the problem. I have inserted these in code behind:

```
private static DispatcherTimer myClickWaitTimer =
    new DispatcherTimer(
        new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1),
        DispatcherPriority.Background,
        mouseWaitTimer_Tick,
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);

private void btnAdd_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
        // Stop the timer from ticking.
        myClickWaitTimer.Stop();

        // Handle Double Click Actions
}

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        myClickWaitTimer.Start();
}

private static void mouseWaitTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        myClickWaitTimer.Stop();

        // Handle Single Click Actions
}
```

So here comes my question. I've removed the **MouseBinding** in XAML and want to call for AddCommand in code behind but I'm having problem to do so due to the **PrismEventAggregator**. The AddCommand in .cs as below:

```
private void AddCommandExecute(Object commandArg)
{
     // Broadcast Prism event for adding item
     this.PrismEventAggregator.GetEvent<AddItemEvent>().Publish(
     new AddItemPayload()
       {
          BlockType = this.BlockType
       }
     );
}
```

Hence would like to know how to call for the **AddCommand** (which is a Prism Event in .cs) in Code behind?

Note: The button is inside resource dictionary thus I failed to use the button name to call for the command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class which will subscribe to the event you are publishing and then execute the logic you want.

For example:

```
public class AddItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public AddItemViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<AddItemEvent>().Subscribe(AddItem);
    }

    private void AddItem(AddItemPayload payload)
    {
        // Your logic here
    }
}
```

Then when you publish the event it will trigger the subscriber and execute.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Expression Blend SDK**, you can create a `Behavior` that encapsulates all your custom logic. This behavior will offer two dependency properties for your command and its parameter, so you can easily create `Binding`s for them, exactly as you do this for your `InputBinding`s.

Move your event handlers and `DispatcherTimer` logic into this behavior:

```
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

class ClickBehavior : Behavior<Button>
{
    // a dependency property for the command
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), 
            typeof(ClickBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    // a dependency property for the command's parameter        
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), 
            typeof(ClickBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)this.GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    // on attaching to a button, subscribe to its Click and MouseDoubleClick events
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.Click += this.AssociatedObject_Click;
        this.AssociatedObject.MouseDoubleClick += this.AssociatedObject_MouseDoubleClick;
    }

    // on detaching, unsubscribe to prevent memory leaks
    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.Click -= this.AssociatedObject_Click;
        this.AssociatedObject.MouseDoubleClick -= this.AssociatedObject_MouseDoubleClick;
    }        

    // move your event handlers here        
    private void AssociatedObject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { //... }        

    private void AssociatedObject_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    { //... }

    // call this method in your event handlers to execute the command
    private void ExecuteCommand()
    {
        if (this.Command != null && this.Command.CanExecute(this.CommandParameter))
        {
            this.Command.Execute(this.CommandParameter);
        }
    }
```

The usage is very simple. You need to declare your additional namespaces:

```
<Window
    xmlns:local="Your.Behavior.Namespace"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    ...
```

Finally, attach the behavior to the button:

```
<Button>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:ClickBehavior Command="{Binding AddCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```